# How to draw on image using finger when image zoom?

Tags: android, image, android-canvas

I am trying to develop draw something on image when image zoom in my project but when zoom then it will be create some offset between touch and drawing but without zoom it is working perfect. For example.
[image]

**Code for image zoom:**

```
@Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

        canvas.concat(matrix);
        ....
    }

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;

        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    matrix.postTranslate((event.getX() - start.x), (event.getY() - start.y));
                } else if (mode == ZOOM && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        float scale = newDist / oldDist;
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null) {
                        float newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, view.getMeasuredWidth() / 2, view.getMeasuredHeight() / 2);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }
        invalidate();

        return true;
    }
```

**Code for drawing:**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {

        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                touchStart(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                touchMove(x, y);
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                touchEnd();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    private void touchMove(float x, float y) {
        float f1 = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float f2 = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if ((f1 >= 4.0F) || (f2 >= 4.0F)) {
            path.quadTo(mX, mY,
                    (x + mX) / 2.0F,
                    (y + mY) / 2.0F);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touchStart(float x, float y) {
        path.reset();
        path.moveTo(x, y);
        blurView.pathList.add(path);
        blurView.strokeWidthList.add(strokeWidth);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touchEnd() {
        path.lineTo(mX, mY);
        path = new Path();
    }
```

can any one help me for how to handle scale factor or how to remove image zoom scale factor into the finger touch.

Answer (score 0):

You usually store the scale factor, and multiplies many of your coordinates handle system by its value.

Simply as that.